# How to print java output in different dynamic excel sheets

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hereby is my code. It is storing the result for one input value. 
I am taking the the number of terms in x variable and the seed value in the y variable. And the input values are coming from one excel file. It is working fine, displaying the result in the other excel file for the input values.
But now i want to display the results for more than one input values lets say 5 number of terms and 5 seed values. For each number of term it will fetch its corresponding seed value and display the series in excel sheet and for next values it should display the result in same file but in next sheet...
Also i am saving file as current date n time...like every time i run the name if the file will be the current date n time which is wrking fine!\
Only problem is with printing result for multiple input values in different sheets of the same file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadFromXLSX {
    static float n1 = 0;
    static float x;
    static float y;

    static void fbc(float x) throws FileNotFoundException {
        {
            float n3;
            if (x > 0) {
                n3 = n1 + y;
                System.out.print(n3);
                System.out.println();
                n1 = y;
                y = n3;
                fbc(x - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void readXLSXFile() throws IOException {
        InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new
                FileInputStream("C://temp/excelfile.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
        XSSFWorkbook test = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row;
        XSSFCell cell;
        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    x = Float.parseFloat(" " +
                            wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(1).getCell(0) + " ");
                    y = Float.parseFloat(" " +
                            wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(1).getCell(1) + " ");
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yy--
                            HH_mm_ss");
                            Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                    String date = dateFormat.format(today);
                    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new
                            FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\temp\\" + date + ".xls")));
                    System.setOut(printStream);
                    System.out.println("The fibonacci series is as
                            follows:-");
                    fbc(x);

                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws
            IOException {

        System.out.println("Program executed
                successfully !!");
        readXLSXFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: @LakmalVithanage I have edited my post with the code. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Printing result for multiple input values in different sheets of the same file, try out as following
Write sheet name for each sheet in your excel file.
Suppose for e.g. Sheet name is "testData",

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("testData");  //Get worksheet of excel file
```

So, get all those corresponding different sheets name of the same file & write output.